# Akamai Sureroute - Path based routing

Tags: akamai

We are using Akamai to route requests from internet to our network. I do not have access to the Akamai configurations/settings to verify how it has been set up or what all features we use. As per information I have, we are using Akamai Sureroute to set up redirection like below -

```
myapp.company.com (apps public URL) > Akamai Edge Server > Akamai Sureroute path > company network load balancer > myapp server
```

Now we have two versions of this "myapp". One running in cloud and another on-prem. Would the below be possible to set up in Akamai -

1. Public URL for accessing both the cloud and on-prem versions should remain the same i.e. myapp.company.com.
2. Based on the path, Akamai should be able to route the request either to cloud load balancer or on-prem load balancer.

**For eg:** myapp.company.com/path1 should go to cloud load balancer > cloud myapp
myapp.company.com/path2 should go to on-prem load balancer > on-prem myapp

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Akamai configurations allow to change the route to origin servers. With using the match conditions, users can go to the different origin servers.

Matches (Path is available for the match condition)
https://techdocs.akamai.com/property-mgr/docs/matches

Add your origin server (Origin Server can be added for the specific condition)
https://techdocs.akamai.com/property-mgr/docs/add-an-origin-server-to-your-property

Comment: Thanks @Hitoshi. Would the sequence of events to be followed be something like mentioned here - https://techdocs.akamai.com/property-mgr/docs/conditional-origins. Will this work with Sureroute configuration?

Comment: SureRoute is the feature to optimize the route to origin server for not cachable contents. This feature is also one of behaviors in Akamai configuration (i.e. It's different from "Origin Server" behavior above.). If there are multiple origin servers, multiple SureRoute behaviors are enabled to optimize a route for each origin server.

https://techdocs.akamai.com/start/docs/sureroute